# Proper way to reload master zone on bind9 doing inline-signing

Tags: bind, dnssec

I have a master BIND9 (v9.10.3) properly serving several signed zones (verified with dnsviz, etc.)

I have not been able to find in any documentation a proper way to reload and resign a static zone file. (my zones are not dynamic). To get updated zones to serve reliably I have had to stop bind, delete the .signed, .signed.jnl and .jbk files, update/replace the zone master file, then restart. Not good, but nothing else I tried worked.

Can I update the zone master then execute (which?) rndc command to reload and resign the zone? And would there be a delay on the results of that operation?

Is there any online DNSSEC BIND admin that you've found helpful?
I have a good number bookmarked but none seemed to address this basic operation, or else I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you describe what happens when you just update the zone normally (expected use)?  https://ftp.isc.org/isc/dnssec-guide/html/dnssec-guide.html may be helpful.

Comment: Also, what does your configuration actually look like more in detail? As something is clearly not working properly this would probably help with understanding what may be up.

Answer (score 3):

When updating the unsigned zone file, be sure to increase the serial number. Depending on your setup (i.e., if using `serial-update-method`) BIND generates new serials on its e.g. when adding NSEC3 RRs. So, it might not be enough to just increase the serial by one, however, you can look it up easily using dig:

```
dig @localhost example.com SOA
```

After updating your zone file, issue a reload:

```
rndc reload
```

**Edit:**

For dynamic zones, issue a

```
rndc freeze
```

before editing the unsigned zone file, and continue accepting dynamic updates afterwards:

```
rndc thaw
```

Answer (score 0):

[The ISC BIND9 Administrator Reference Manual](https://ftp.isc.org/isc/bind9/cur/9.10/doc/arm/Bv9ARM.pdf) has extensive documentation on DNSSEC, rndc, and auto-dnssec (the particular feature you're looking for).

Comment: For DNSSEC specifically, https://ftp.isc.org/isc/dnssec-guide/html/dnssec-guide.html has more in-depth info on the overall setup.